# return data and error messages to ng-message via ajax return

Tags: angularjs

I'm very new to angularjs and i'm trying to find a way how i can translate the following jquery into angularjs

```
jquery
$("element").html("some text here");
```

I found something like this but it wont apply

```
<div ng-init="obj = {greet: false}">
    <ng-messages for="obj">
         <ng-message when="greet">Show me</ng-message>
    </ng-messages>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i omit the description of the modules and controllers, you'll have something like that :
in the js : $scope.myValue = "a value";
in the html : `<div>{{myValue}}</div>`

ng-messages test if the expression is true, and show ng-message if it is.
I'm not sure, that it does what you're searching for.